# Solr block join faceting while maintaining original query

Tags: solr, lucene

I am attempting to implement a search in solr 5.5 which requires faceting on child document fields. I realize that flattening the data structure is the ideal solution for solr search but unfortunately because of business requirements of the search, I am required to maintain a relationship between various fields (hence the child documents).

I am experimenting with using the **BlockJoinFacetComponent** to facet on child document fields, and I am able to get everything working and get the counts I expect using the basic example, no problems there. The issue I am facing is that the **BlockJoinFacetComponent** requires a **ToParentQuery**, and I can't figure out how to combine this with my original search query and still get facet results.

To explain further:

I am basically following this example: http://www.slideshare.net/lucidworks/faceting-with-lucene-block-join-query-oleg-savrasov

In the example, the user originally searches for "dress", and then is shown facets to filter down by size, color. Size and Color are child fields, and the **BlockJoinFacetComponent** is used in the example to facet by size and color and retrieve the expected counts.

In the example, the query used to retrieve said facets (slide 22) is:

```
q= {!parent which="scope:product"} COLOR: Blue
child.facet.field = SIZE
```

Which works fine. What I am not understanding is in this example we have now lost the original search for "dress". So my question is basically how can I combine my original search (dress) with the **ToParentQuery**? I have tried everything I can think of to combine the queries, but I always end up getting the same exception:

```
"Block join faceting is allowed with ToParentBlockJoinQuery only".
```

I have even downloaded the solr source code and hooked up a remote debugger where this error is being thrown to try and debug this, but I still can't figure it out. No matter what I do it seems like unless the **ToParentBlockJoinQuery** is the only thing in the query, the **BlockJoinFacetComponent** will reject it. Which seems odd considering to use the component you've now lost what the user originally searched for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further debugging, the issue stems from the fact that BlockJoinFacetComponent seems to not be able to separate the ToParentBlockJoinQuery portion of a query if you are using a query parser other than the standard parser (I was using edismax).

For example, with the standard query parser, this works:

```
"original query" + _query_:"{!parent which="scope:product"} COLOR: Blue"
child.facet.field = SIZE
```

If you run this same query with a dismax or edismax query parser, you receive the error:

```
"Block join faceting is allowed with ToParentBlockJoinQuery only".
```

Since I am dependent on the edismax query parser, this was a show stopper for me. However, I was able to achieve the results I desired instead by using the JSON Facet API: http://yonik.com/solr-nested-objects/#faceting